# Can I know if Solve found all the solutions ? (Equation with integers)

Tags: equation-solving

I have this inequation to solve.

```
Solve[Min[j2 + j3, j5 + j6] - Max[Abs[j2 - j3], Abs[j5 - j6]] >= 
   2 &&  Min[j2 + j6, j5 + j3] - Max[Abs[j2 - j6], Abs[j5 - j3]] >= 
   2, {j2, j3, j5, j6}, Integers]
```

Mathematica answers me a lot of solutions. But I want to know if there are all the solutions.

How can I do that ? Am I sure if when it doesn't warning me, then I must have all the solutions ?

Comment: Try Reduce instead of Solve.

Comment: Yes it finds more answers thanks. But how can I know if there are all the solutions ? Is it possible ?

Comment: There are an infinite number of solutions, `Simplify[ expr , 
 Assumptions -> {j2 == j3, j5 == j6, j6 >= j3, j3 > 1} ]  (*True*) `